# Pandas groupby index.month_name

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

**Code**

```
def plot_data_by_month(data, x, y) :
    data_by_month = data[data[y] > 0].groupby(data[data[y] > 0].index.month_name())[y].mean()

    ax = data_by_month.plot(figsize=(15, 10))
    ax.set_title(y + ' ' + 'by Month of Year')
    ax.set_xlabel('Month')
    ax.set_ylabel(y)
    time_labels = data_by_month.index
    ticks = ax.set_xticks(range(len(time_labels)), time_labels)

plot_data_by_month(chiller1, 'Time', 'kWE')
```

**Outcome**

[Picture of graph (Can't imbed photos yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXWut.png)

Not sure how to get the months out of alphabetical order and into calender order, the data frame is order from oldest - newest (Jan - Dec) so not sure how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter rows only once to helper DataFrame `df1`, if necessary sorting `DatetimeIndex` and for prevent sorting add `sort=False` to `groupby`:

```
df1 = data[data[y] > 0].sort_index()
data_by_month = df1.groupby(df1.index.month_name(), sort=False)[y].mean()
```

instead:

```
data_by_month = data[data[y] > 0].groupby(data[data[y] > 0].index.month_name())[y].mean()
```

Comment: Looks like its solved my issue. What does the .sort_index() do?

Comment: @JackLang - it sorting DatatimeIndex.